# JavaFX 2.0 Choicebox - Has anyone implemented an editable choice box?

Tags: javafx-2

The current choice box in JavaFX 2.0 seems limited..  Looking to hack in an "editable" one.  Has anyone implemented one yet?  Or does anyone have a suggested strategy for doing so?  My initial thought is to create a textbox that appears on a key event to the choice box.

My second thought is a "Roll my own" but haven't thought much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Look for ComboBox. It can be editable (there is editable property)
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be included into JavaFX 2.1.

You can download developers preview here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html